# How to add a Field to Phone List view in Outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook, add-in

I am developing a small add-in for Outlook. I need to add a field to the Phone List called "Is Available", and it should be a Yes / No field. I know how to add buttons to a toolbar but haven't really found something about adding a field to the Phone List grid in Outlook. Any pointers to a tutorial or directions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the view using Explorer.CurrentView.
Keep in mind that you cannot dynamically update any fields in the view unless they are actually set on the corresponding item, which sounds like a problem in your case.

Comment: SO i can add a column in the Phone List this way?, is there a tutorial that you may know of about this btw?. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864185(v=office.15).aspx